# cannot find protractor-result folder 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter'

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I'm trying to generate reports in Protractor and i followed [this](http://www.blaiseliu.com/set-up-protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/) tutorial to do that.

Here is my `conf.js` file.

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
    baseDirectory: 'D:/My Work/Protractor/Financial/protractor-result', // a location to store screen shots.    
    docTitle: 'Protractor Demo Reporter',
    docName: 'protractor-demo-tests-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['invoice.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
  }
}
```

I tried run this using command `protractor conf.js` and there's no folder generated containing test results. If I use command, `protractor specs\configurations.js` following error occurs.

```
ERROR - failed loading configuration file specs/conf.js
C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\configParser.js:
204
    throw e;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\specs\conf.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\lib\configParser.js:195:22)
    at Object.init (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
lib\launcher.js:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\lib\cli.js:140:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
```

Why can't I  generate reports?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Where are you using `jasmine-reporters` ? You are using `protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` which works with outdated jasmine 1.x version. Why don't you try to update your stuff and use a different reporter that is compatible with `jasmine2`.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question title. Can you suggest areporter that is compatible with jasmine2? :)

Comment: Here's one - https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changesd my conf.js as this.

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'D:/My Work/Protractor/Financial/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['invoice.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
  },
 // Setup the report before any tests start
   beforeLaunch: function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve){
        reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
      });
   },

   // Assign the test reporter to each running instance
   onPrepare: function() {
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
   },

   // Close the report after all tests finish
   afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve){
        reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
      });
   }
}
```

Then I used `npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter --save-dev` command to install npm.

Working now. :)